# How can I go back a directory in an "ftp_put" file path?

Tags: php, upload, ftp, directory

I have a page where users of my website can change the info they have entered in for their account (e.g. real name, email, and avatar). What I want to do is let them change their avatar. It's all been goin' good except for the last part of it all: uploading the file. First I found the file, then resized it, and now I'm tryin' to upload it to my server via the `"ftp_put"` method in PHP.

The script I'm using is in (from my site's root directory) the folder `"/scripts/newavatar.php"`. The folder I'm trying to upload into is `"/avatars/"`. My problem is that FTP won't recognize that I've entered in `"public_html/avatars"` or `"../avatars/"`, or it shouldn't or something. I don't know how to explain it any better. Can someone please help me?

Comment: Wait, isn't the file already on your server after being uploaded via PHP? You should only need to use [`move_uploaded_file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php)

Comment: Well, I'm actually creating another file from the temporary file. What I'm doing is using the `imagecreatefrompng` method in PHP. Then I do some resizing and what not, eventually leading to uploading this new image that is completely new. It's difficult to understand a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

You should use full FTP path to "avatars" folder.
If it is located in FTP root directory, try:

```
ftp_put($conn_id, "/avatars/" . $file_name, $local_file_name, FTP_BINARY);
```

Comment: Thanks @Vladislav, but it still didn't work out. I'm getting the error `Warning: imagepng() [function.imagepng]: Unable to open '/avatars/072720113909.png' for writing: No such file or directory in /home/artfulme/public_html/scripts/newavatar.php on line 60` and `Warning: ftp_put() [function.ftp-put]: Can't open that file: No such file or directory in /home/artfulme/public_html/scripts/newavatar.php on line 67`. I'm not sure what's goin' on at this point :P

Comment: I think you should use relative path in imagepng: "../avatars/072720113909.png".

Answer (score 0):

The image file is already on your server so you don't need to use FTP methods.

Here's how you do it

1. Upload file via form
2. Load file into `imagecreatefrompng()` or similar via the `$_FILES['field_name']['tmp_name']` path
3. Make changes / resize
4. Save the file to its final destination using `imagepng($imageResource, '/path/to/avatars/image-file-name.png')`

### Update

I'm guessing you're having a bit of trouble understanding server-side paths. It's probably easiest for you to use a path relative to your `scripts/newavatar.php` file when saving the final image. To do so, use the special `__FILE__` constant, eg

```
// save final image
imagepng($imageResource, dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/avatars/' . $imageFilename);
```

Comment: My website isn't being hosted locally with Apache or something, it's via an online web-host, so I'm not sure how to do that. Are you saying to upload via FTP, then edit it?

Comment: @Johnny How are new avatar images submitted for resizing? Do you have a form on your site with an `<input type="file" name="avatar">` element?

Answer (score 0):

You should pay attention to difference between **remote_file** and **local_file**.
**local_file** can be any relative path and directory but **remote_file** is a file name in remote server and it's better to not use relative path and only use the file name.
For example:

```
remote_file = "1532574888.exe";
local_file = "../../files/cleaned/1532574888.exe";
ftp_put($ftp_conn, $remote_file, $local_file, FTP_ASCII);
```

It works for me.